# Xcode 7 slow and sluggish

Tags: xcode, performance

Since upgrading to xcode 7 and greater, the performance of xcode is terrible. When I click on a class or scroll the code pane it sometimes takes up to 30 seconds before reacting and often I need to force quit xcode and restart.

I have turned off source control and I am not using swift.

I have a new macbook pro with 8gb memory and an SSD. my computer is fast and has no other performance issues.

-UPDATE-
I have cleared derived data and am not using any unusual plugins

Does anyone know what may be the problem? I imagine some build setting is causing this but im not sure which.

Comment: Are you sure you only have XCode running? When i had slowing Mac problem i realise that there is too much of Safari opened windows. Use activity indicator to find out what takes memory or CPU.

Comment: did you try quitting all and reboot?

Comment: Or build a Hackintosh - that gives Mac Pro performance for £400.

Comment: Use Activity Monitor to determine which processes are using the CPU time. Note: I had very sluggish response on 10.11 and found that I needed to exclude some mounted backups from Spotlight.

Comment: I don't think that's a right place to ask this question - rather http://apple.stackexchange.com/. Anyway, I have a new macbook pro with 16gb ram and ssd. My Xcode works perfectly. Did you try to delete derived data for your project and wait until it indexes it properly? Also, if you use some plugins, they may cause some issues.

Comment: Do you have any designable views and do you have a storyboard open? This will cause Xcode to build your project every 30 second or so (even more often if you make changes to files) and will spike your CPU usage.

Comment: @Vive -"Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers". Xcode is a tool used by programmers and this question may pertain to compile settings etc. This is certainly the place to ask.

Comment: @Zigglzworth better to quote the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development..."

Comment: Moderator deleted my answer for this problem. here's the blogpost related to this problem if anybody is interested: http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.my/2016/05/how-to-fix-xcode-7-lag_17.html

Comment: After upgrading to Xcode 7.3 (7D175) this problem seems to have gone away

Answer (score 0):

The issue is totally with xcode 7.

try to commit/save every time you make some changes, it will increase some performance